# How to use annotation layer in PDF.js?

Tags: javascript, pdf, firefox, pdf.js

Some of the PDF.js code mentions an "annotation layer", for example AnnotationLayerBuilder here:

https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/95e102c07bc257c2120fd7fd9141762b2c813a1c/web/annotation_layer_builder.js#L118

There is also `pdfDocument.annotationStorage` and `pdfjsLib.AnnotationLayer`, which - on all the documents I've tried - are empty, even in documents which do have text annotations.

I couldn't find any examples or documentation on the annotation layer and how it is supposed to be used, but it sure sounds interesting :)

1. What *is* the annotation layer?  Is this talking about standard PDF annotations, as described in https://pspdfkit.com/blog/2018/what-are-annotations/ or https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf section 8.4 Annotations?  Or, is it something internal to PDF.js?
2. How do I list the existing annotations from javascript code in PDF.js, and how do I add one?  (just for display; not expecting to be able to save it in the pdf, of course)  Can anyone provide a working code example?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Annotations are standard for the PDF file format as described in the links you provided. They are not a new concept to PDF.js.

How you get the annotations will depend on your situation. I'm building a view layer to replace the viewer the PDF.js team built. The basic idea there is you:

1. Get a reference to the PDFDocumentProxy object via `const doc = getDocument(url)`
2. Get a reference to a PDFPageProxy object via `const page = await doc.getPage(num)`
3. Get the annotations via `await page.getAnnotations()`

If you're already using the viewer they built, it doesn't appear to be exposed anywhere.

Comment: Also, the annotation data they expose is limited. Square annotations, for example, don't include the fill color. Stamp annotations have no useful information in them but the location on the page.

Comment: is this still true?  I'm about to start building a tool to extract specific annotations and would rather not learn this the hard way.

Comment: @JimB. Curious if you found out more about this - please post an answer if you have more info :)  Thanks!

Comment: The older PDF annotation layers for PDF.js were deprecated in 2018 (see https://github.com/instructure/pdf-annotate.js). A fairly active fork of it is being maintained here: https://github.com/Submitty/pdf-annotate.js. Additionally, new annotation capabilities are being added into PDF.js right now (March 2024), as tracked in https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/projects/9